# ffmpeg mpegts udp stream unexpectedly producing dramatically increased packet rate

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video

I am using an ffmpeg 3.4.5 process to stream MPEG-TS video from a computer's screen to a recorder.  The recorder effectively captures network traffic (like a promiscuous wireshark) and produces a `.cap` file.  The command line I'm using is:

```
ffmpeg -v -8 -y -f fbdev -i /dev/fb0 -filter:v "crop=640:480:0:0" -threads 2 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -x264opts crf=20:vbv-maxrate=3000:vbv-bufsize=150:intra-refresh=1:slice-max-size=1500:keyint=30:ref=1 -f mpegts udp://$RECORDER_IP:1235?pkt_size=188&buffer_size=65535
```

As you can see from the command line, the input is the Linux frame buffer.

The video then needs to be reassembled from the `.cap` file, and I have been doing this essentially by concatenating the payloads of the UDP datagrams and putting the data in a `.ts` file.  This has been working reasonably well for a long time.

Recently I started encountering issues where the `.cap` file contains an increased number of packets per unit time compared to what I've seen before.  This is resulting in an extracted `.ts` file that plays back in slow motion.  This appears to happen only sometimes.  I have `.cap` files that show a normal packet rate (about 650 packets/sec), and others that have a 3.75x packet rate, without having changed any ffmpeg options or recorder settings.

I even have a `.cap` file that was created when two identical ffmpeg processes were running simultaneously, with the only difference being in the destination IP address supplied on the command line, and I can see the packets going to one IP address at the normal rate and the packets going to the other IP address at a much greater rate within the same `.cap` file.

I don't understand why I'm seeing packets at different rates.  Ultimately I need to get the reassembled video files to play back at the proper speed reliably.

How can I accomplish this?  Are there better arguments I might put on the ffmpeg command line to avoid changes in the packet rate?  Are there any other potential causes that come to mind?

Thanks in advance!